# Does the Euclidean algorithm work on an integral domain?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, proof-explanation

Let $D$ be an integral domain, and $b(x)\in D[x]$ a polynomial such as $\deg(b)\ge0$.

Prove that for all $a(x) \in D[x]$, $p(x), r(x) \in D[x]$ exists such that $a(x)=b(x)p(x)+r(x)$ with $\deg(r)<\deg(b)$, so that the leading coefficient of $b(x)$ is a unit.

I need to know how to prove that the coefficient of $b(x)$ is actually a unit.

Comment: Welcome to MathExchange. Please read MathJax grammar.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.